# How to validate VB.NET Login form with radion buttons?

Tags: vb.net

Please help. I have a VB.NET login form with a Username (textbox name txtUsername), Password(textbox name txtPassword) and 3 radio buttons (rbAdmin, rbSec and rbTreasure. The username and password values are taken from SQL Server database table UserDetails. I want the login form to allow logging in for the user with the correct combination of correct username and password and the correct radio button.

E.G. If my username is 'john' and my password is 'johns' and i am a secretary (selected radio button rbSec).

I have only managed to login after verifying the Username and Password, for the radio buttons I have failed. Can someone help please. Below is the code i have tried:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmLogin

    Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
        Try
            If txtUsername.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("All fields are required.")
                Return
            ElseIf txtPassword.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("All fields are required.")
                Return
            ElseIf rbAdmin.Checked = False And rbSec.Checked = False And rbTreasurer.Checked = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Select the user type!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Data Source=JUNIOR-PC;Initial Catalog=TBSociety;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=adminadmin")
                    conn.Open()

                    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserDetails where UserName = '" & txtUsername.Text & "' and Password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ", conn)
                    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "UserDetails")

                    If ds.Tables("UserDetails").Rows.Count > 0 And ds.Tables("UserDetails").Rows.Count < 2 Then
                        If rbAdmin.Checked = True Then
                            Me.Hide()
                            frmHome.Show()
                        ElseIf rbSec.Checked = True Then
                            MsgBox("You will have limited access to parts of the system.")
                            Me.Hide()
                            frmHome.Show()
                        End If

                    End If

                End Using

            End If
            Me.Hide()
            frmHome.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR5", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

Here is the code after I have modified according to your suggestions, @Pradeep Kumar. But on running it I get an error message which reads as "Must declare scalar variable @Username". Please correct me again on this. I just think its a stupid error which i cant rectify.

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Try
        If txtUsername.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("All fields are required.")
            Return
        ElseIf txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("All fields are required.")
            Return
        ElseIf Not rbAdmin.Checked AndAlso Not rbSec.Checked AndAlso Not rbTreasurer.Checked Then
            MessageBox.Show("Select the user type!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Else
            Dim recordsFound As Integer
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=Junior-PC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=adminadmin;Initial Catalog=TBSociety")
                conn.Open()

                Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logins where Username = @Username and Password = @Password and Designation = @Designation", conn)
                If rbAdmin.Checked Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", "Admin")
                ElseIf rbSec.Checked Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", "Secretary")
                ElseIf rbTreasurer.Checked Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", "Treasurer")
                End If
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", txtUsername.Text)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)
                recordsFound = command.ExecuteScalar
            End Using
            If recordsFound > 0 Then
                If rbAdmin.Checked Then
                    txtUsername.Text = ""
                    txtPassword.Text = ""
                    rbAdmin.Checked = False
                    rbSec.Checked = False
                    rbTreasurer.Checked = False
                    Me.Hide()
                    frmHome.Show()
                ElseIf rbSec.Checked Then
                    txtUsername.Text = ""
                    txtPassword.Text = ""
                    rbAdmin.Checked = False
                    rbSec.Checked = False
                    rbTreasurer.Checked = False
                    Me.Hide()
                    frmHome.AttendanceRegisterToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.AdminTasksToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.Show()
                ElseIf rbTreasurer.Checked Then
                    frmHome.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Junior\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TBSSystem\TBSSystem\Resources\OFFISUPP.gif")
                    frmHome.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile
                    frmHome.MemberToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.MemberRecordsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.AttendanceRegisterToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.SecretarialServicesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.LogFileToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.AdminTasksToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                    frmHome.Show()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name, Password or Designation. Try again...")
                    Me.Hide()
                    frmHome.Show()
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR5", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with *Embedding MS word into VB.NET 2010*?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. Thank for alerting me on that. I have corrected it now.

Comment: You don't need a `DataSet` or `DataAdapter` for this small task. You can easily do with `Command.ExecuteScalar` which returns just a single value.

Comment: Are the radio button values being stored in db? Or is it that for a given login, you can choose your access type through the radio button? And at 1st sight, i think the connection instantiation should go in anothe `ELSE` block, right?

Comment: You seem to have your database retrieval code in the wrong part of your If.. End If structure!

Comment: Nadeem_MK, Yes I do have a database table Designation with 2 columns (DesgID, Designation). The table store the radio buttons values. I will also appreciate it even if the access is through choosing a radio button of that user type.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use of `Parameters` is recommended over string concatenated SQL
   query.
2. You don't need a `DataSet` or `DataAdapter` for this small task. You can easily do with `Command.ExecuteScalar` which returns just a single value.

You can read more about command and parameters here: [Commands and Parameters (MSDN).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is some untested code that would work for you. Note that I have assumed that your table has a `Designation` column (varchar type) and has values like Admin, Secretary, Treasurer. If this is not the case, you would need to make appropriate modifications.

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Try
        If txtUsername.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("All fields are required.")
            Return
        ElseIf txtPassword.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("All fields are required.")
            Return
        ElseIf Not rbAdmin.Checked AndAlso Not rbSec.Checked AndAlso Not rbTreasurer.Checked Then
            MessageBox.Show("Select the user type!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Else
            Dim recordsFound As Integer
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Data Source=JUNIOR-PC;Initial Catalog=TBSociety;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=adminadmin")
                conn.Open()
                Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserDetails where UserName = @UserName and Password = @Password and Designation = @Designation", conn)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)
                If rbAdmin.Checked Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", "Admin")
                ElseIf rbSec.Checked Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", "Secretary")
                ElseIf rbTreasurer.Checked Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", "Treasurer")
                End If
                recordsFound = CType(command.ExecuteScalar, Integer)
            End Using
            If recordsFound > 0 Then
                If rbAdmin.Checked Then
                    'nothing special
                ElseIf rbSec.Checked Then
                    MsgBox("You will have limited access to parts of the system.")
                ElseIf rbTreasurer.Checked Then
                    MsgBox("whatever message you want to show......")
                End If
                Me.Hide()
                frmHome.Show()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name, Password or Designation. Try again...")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR5", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I have learned a lot from this code but on Modifying it I could not successfully go right. I ended up using a similar method like the code I pasted above. But now the user can successfully log into the system BUT as any of the three user-types (Admin, Secretary and Treasurer as long as the username and password are correct and this is NOT what I want.

Comment: Do you have a Desination column in your UserDetails table? Does it store values like Admin, Secretary, Treasurer etc., or numeric values linked to another table?

Comment: Yes the User details table has the column Designation and there are  Admin, Secretary and Treasurer as user type values.

Comment: What happens if you execute the following query directly against the database: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserDetails where UserName = @UserName and Password = @Password and Designation = @Designation`   (replace @UserName, @Password, @Designation with correct values)

Comment: The query returns count as 1.

Comment: Then the above code should work too. It is doing nothing special. You said you ended up using a "similar method". So probably whatever edits you made may be causing the problem.